# empty elements in symfony form collection

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have a simple form with collection of items in it. Just like described here:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html.

The problem is when I add new element (or multiple elements) WITHOUT touching enything in them (not changing theirs inputs) I get an empty collection.

I would like to get a collection of added elements regardless theirs content. And even if there are fields are empty it would be ok.

In my case after form submission I have:

```
var_dump($request->get('my_form_name'));

/* dump result: 
array (size=19)
   ...
   'partners' => 
    array (size=1)
        0 => 
          array (size=2)
            'fullname' => string '' (length=2)
            'manager' => string '' (length=0)
   ...
*/

var_dump($form->getData()->getPartners()); 
// EMPTY!!! WTF? I expect an array of 1 element of Partner class which fields are set to '' and ''
```

On the other hand if somethig is set then it is ok:

```
var_dump($request->get('my_form_name'));

/* dump result: 
array (size=19)
   ...
   'partners' => 
    array (size=1)
        0 => 
          array (size=2)
            'fullname' => string ' NAME HERE ' (length=2)
            'manager' => string '' (length=0)
   ...
*/

var_dump($form->getData()->getPartners()); 
// ok, we have an array of 1 element which is an object of Partner class
```

Any ideas how to get rid of that bug?

---

**UPDATED**

Partner's class mapping is:

```
Bundle\Entity\Partner:
  ...
  fields:
    fullname: 
      type: string
      lenght: 255
      nullable: True
    manager: 
      type: string
      lenght: 255
      nullable: True
  manyToOne:
    owner:
      targetEntity: Step2
      inversedBy: partners
      joinColumn:
        name: owner_id
        referencedColumnName: id
```

field `partners` is added to the form of `Step2` entity like `collection` with `allow_add`, `allow_delete`, `by_reference` set to `false`

Comment: Did you associate the 'partner' class to your form ? If yes, what annotations are on the 'fullname' attribute of you 'partner' entity class ?

Comment: I updated my question to provide more information

Comment: Can you show your form code? It looks like you have `mapped => false` option set.

Comment: Please provide you code for generate form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I found a problem.

I must to set `empty_data` in subform (*Partner* class).

---

I don't understand why but when all fields of related class (Partners) are submitted to be `""` (empty) then in method `sumbit` of class `Symfony\Component\Form\Form` the block

```
            if (FormUtil::isEmpty($viewData)) {
                $emptyData = $this->config->getEmptyData();

                if ($emptyData instanceof \Closure) {
                    /* @var \Closure $emptyData */
                    $emptyData = $emptyData($this, $viewData);
                }

                $viewData = $emptyData;
            }
```

gives `null` in $`viewData` for *Partner* of empty fields. For object submitted to be the *Partner* with at least one field not empty `$viewData` is needed object.

---

All that is because

```
$this->config->getEmptyData()
```

for empty object is `Closure` which eventually results to `null`, but for `Partner` with at least one field not empty it gives directly needed object.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass second parameter to `submit()` method as `false`. It will say to Form component that submitted empty data must not change any existing data.

```php
$form->submit($request->get('my_form_name'), false);
```

Comment: This should work. I didn't know about the second parameter of this `submit`. Usually I use `handleRequest`. I suppose there is no way to do it still using `handleRequest`?

Comment: No. You need to use submit instead. `handleRequest()` just call `submit()` with data received from Request.